# Finding all upper/lower case combinations of a word

Tags: java, optimization

For every word there are 2^n different ways of writing the word if you take into account upper/lower case letters. Eg for "word" we can write;

- word
- Word
- wOrd
- WOrd
- woRd
- WoRd
- etc

I've written this code to calculate all the combinations. Is there any way I can improve the performance? Profiling tells me that this method takes 99.9% of the execution time of my program (which measures password strength).

```
String word = "word";
int combinations = 1 << word.length();   

for (int i=0; i<combinations; i++) {
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(word);
  for (int j=0; j<word.length(); j++) {
    if ((i & 1<<j) != 0) {
      String s = word.substring(j, j+1).toUpperCase();
      buf.replace(j, j+1, s);
    }
  }
  System.out.println(buf);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to *know* all possible combinations if all you want to know is the strength of the password?

Comment: This is a brute strength algorithm.  If it seems slow, it's because your algorithm is O(2^n) where n is the length of the word you're trying.  There's a good reason why it's slow and it's the same reason passwords aren't easily crackable.

Comment: Why do you have to calculate all combinations to measure password strength? I absolutely see no benefit. I'm sure there are much faster algorithms for measuring password strength.

Comment: For measuring such things, you generally need to count the combinations, not 'have' all of them.

You already know that it's 2^n, you just need to find out the n - i.e., count how many of the symbols are case-sensitive (letters), and then calculate the 2^n formula.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void comb(String word) {
    int combinations = 1 << word.length();
    char[][] chars = { word.toLowerCase().toCharArray(),
                       word.toUpperCase().toCharArray() };
    char[] result = new char[word.length()]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < combinations; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
            result[j] = chars[(i >> j) & 1][j];
        }
        System.out.println(new String(result));
    }
}
```

**[Edit]**

I did some profiling, and my version seems slightly better, and the following version is even a little bit faster:

```
public static void comb(String word) {
    word = word.toLowerCase();    
    int combinations = 1 << word.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < combinations; i++) {
        char[] result = word.toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
            if (((i >> j) & 1) == 1 ) {
               result[j] = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(j));
            }   
        }
        System.out.println(new String(result));
    }
}
```

However, all versions so far are in the same ballpark and won't change something substantial, because `System.out.println` dominates the performance.

**[Edit 2]**

The algorithm really doesn't matter much, the `System.out.println` impact is too heavy. Collection everything in a `StringBuilder` and calling `System.out.println` doesn't help either. However, quite surprisingly my profiler tells me that this simple recursive version performs best:

```
public static void comb4(String word) {
    comb4(word,new char[word.length()],0);
}    

private static void comb4(String word, char[] accu, int index) {
    if(index == word.length()) {
        System.out.println(accu);
    } else {
        char ch = word.charAt(index);
        accu[index] = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        comb4(word, accu , index+1);
        accu[index] = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
        comb4(word, accu, index+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we agree that `just posting code` without explanations is bad practice?

Comment: The snippet is short, the changes are obvious, the general functioning is the same. 'nuff said.

Comment: nice idea, but this implementation doubles my execution time.

Comment: Landei's solution is faster for me (I admit: a single run with `wordingitalldaylong`, redirected to stdout 0.96s Landei-, 2.05s QWerky-code.

Comment: Hmmm, then I'd guess that for short words the overhead for calling toLowerCase and toUpperCase is too big, while for longer words the tighter loop wins. Probably a version without the Array `chars`, but using `Character.toUpper` and `Character.toLower` on `word.charAt(j)` would be better. Obviously some profiling could be helpful.